# How do I integrate collective.documentviewer with my custom Dexterity type?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I'm trying to use [newly released support](https://github.com/collective/collective.documentviewer/commit/9d061b41564d702dd63443ccbe5b1ac0c514942f) for custom Dexterity types in `collective.documentviewer` but struggling to make it work properly.

I have confirmed support exists for `ATFile`, but not my type:

[image]

As far as I can tell, I've satisfied the four requirements for support:

- Implement IDexterityContent (which my Dexterity Container type should do by default)
- Define a primary field, which I do here: https://github.com/collective/collective.pece/blob/master/collective/pece/content/document_artifact.py
- Add the documentviewer view to my type: https://github.com/collective/collective.pece/blob/master/collective/pece/profiles/default/types/document_artifact.xml#L21
- Upload a supported type: PDF is selected by default.

Unfortunately I get: "The file is not a supported document type. Your type may be supported. Check out the document viewer configuration settings."

Am I missing something obvious or is it code digging time? Thank you

Comment: Is there anything I can do to make this question more answerable?

Comment: 404 for the files you link to...

Comment: It worked straight for me. I installed the buildout and requirements for documentviewer (docsplit, graphicsmagick, ghostscript and poppler). I uploaded a PDF file and was converted OK. Did you try with different PDF files? Can you provide your PDF?

Comment: Yeah! collective.peace and requirements of documentviewer.

Comment: @marcosfromero Thanks. Weird… I did not try different PDFs but I tried the same PDF in both ATFile and document_artifact. If it works in ATFile I'd expect it to work in document_artifact.